# Xcode 7 - Can't call AudioFileStreamOpen

Tags: ios, macos, swift, audio

I can't seem to wrap my head around this issue. Trying to play with **Audio File Stream Services**.

Some code:

```
import Foundation
import AudioToolbox

public class StreamingPlayback {
    var audioFileStream: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioFileStreamID>?
    var inClientData: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void> = nil

    init() {
    }

    func start () {
        AudioFileStreamOpen(&inClientData, propertyProc, packetProc, kAudioFileMP3Type, &audioFileStream)
    }

    func propertyProc(inClientData: UnsafeMutablePointer<()>,inFileStreamId: AudioFileStreamID,inPropertyId: AudioFileStreamPropertyID,ioFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>) -> Void {
    }

    func packetProc(inClientData: UnsafeMutablePointer<()>,inNumberOfBytes: UInt32,inNumberOfPackets: UInt32, UnsafeMutablePointer<()>, inPacketDescriptions: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>) -> Void {
    }
}
```

This gives me :

```
Cannot invoke 'AudioFileStreamOpen' with an argument list of type '(inout UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, (UnsafeMutablePointer<()>, inFileStreamId: AudioFileStreamID, inPropertyId: AudioFileStreamPropertyID, ioFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>) -> Void, (UnsafeMutablePointer<()>, inNumberOfBytes: UInt32, inNumberOfPackets: UInt32, UnsafeMutablePointer<()>, inPacketDescriptions: UnsafePointer<AudioStreamPacketDescription>) -> Void, AudioFileTypeID, inout UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioFileStreamID>?)'

Expected an argument list of type '(UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, AudioFileStream_PropertyListenerProc, AudioFileStream_PacketsProc, AudioFileTypeID, UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioFileStreamID>)'
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue. Even though Swift 2.0 supports c function callbacks, there are still some wonkiness going on. I did find a workaround though.  try this :

```
@objc protocol HandleAudioPacketsDelegate {
    func handlePacketsProc(ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
        inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
        inBufNumber: UInt32,
        inNumberFrames: UInt32,
        ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus
}

func packetsProc(inRefCon: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>,
    ioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBufNumber: UInt32,
    inNumberFrames: UInt32,
    ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>)
    -> OSStatus
{
    let delegate = unsafeBitCast(inRefCon, HandleAudioPacketsDelegate.self)
    let result = delegate.handlePacketsProc(ioActionFlags,
        inTimeStamp: inTimeStamp,
        inBufNumber: inBufNumber,
        inNumberFrames: inNumberFrames,
        ioData: ioData)
    return result
}
```

then in your `StreamingPlayback` class use this method for the callback:

```
func handlePacketsProcioActionFlags: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioUnitRenderActionFlags>,
    inTimeStamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>,
    inBufNumber: UInt32,
    inNumberFrames: UInt32,
    ioData: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>) -> OSStatus {
}
```

Comment: I can walk you through this over skype/email/fb messenger. Also would love to talk audio streaming/swift if you're up for it. There's a lot of hurdles around the combination and there's only a small community that knows about working with the two. Whats your contact info?